# Get Relative message number from UID in IMAP?

Tags: imap

In IMAP it's pretty straightforward to get the UID for a single message if you happen to have a relative message number:

```
FETCH 1 (UID)
```

But suppose you had a UID and later wanted to determine the relative message number for just that message? Does IMAP provide a way to do that?

I'm not seeing anything especially obvious in the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) that would allow you to get the relative message number for a single message. I could do

```
UID FETCH 1:* (UID)
```

and then parse and search through the results to find it, but that seems like overkill (not to mention exponentially slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
tag UID FETCH <uid> (UID)
```

The response will include the message number, not in the fetch information but as the initial part of the response

```
tag <messagenumber> FETCH (UID <uid>)
```